# SQL server multiple like query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to use multiple like query for column 1 and want show the data in seperate column, can I do

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), DECRYPTBYKEY(ssr.optiontextresponse)) AS DueDate  
  
  FROM [dbo].[tblsubscribeReport] ssr    
  INNER JOIN [dbo].[tblsurveyque] sq on sq.surveyquestionid = CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), DECRYPTBYKEY(ssr.questionid))  --and [name] LIKE '%due%'
  LEFT JOIN [dbo].[tblsurveyquestiono] so on so.surveyquestionoptionid = CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), DECRYPTBYKEY(ssr.optionid)) 
  JOIN tblSubscribers s on s.SubscriberID = ssr.SubscriberId 
  WHERE 
  s.ClientID = '12'
  and (sq.[name] LIKE '%due%' OR sq.[name] LIKE '%doc%' )
```

| Due date |
| --- |
| Feb 16, 2023 |
| Shailesh Parihar |
| Feb 17 2023 |
| Meet |
| Ank |
| feb 18 2023 |
| Maria |
| Mar 2 2023 |
| Mar 12 2023 |
| Joun |
| Mar 11 2023 |
| Smith |
| 14/02/2023 |
| Sarah |
| 15-02-2023 |
| Peggy |

I Want show the my data in separate column

Comment: add parenthesis around the OR statement or else you get all row with the name doc the doesn't have the client id 12

Comment: I am not able to understand your goal?

Comment: Okay, I found one user's details in multiple rows, such as the first row showing the user's date and the second row showing the next data; essentially, I want all the data in a single row using multiple LIKE  SQL query. E.g first column is Date and second column is doctor name, see my output.